# Get the content of an element based on its attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How do i get the content of the element with attribute `name="html_header"` using JavaScript?

This is the HTML:

```
<view name="html_header"> //some content </view>
<view name="html_body"> //some content </view>
```

This is the current JavaScript:

```
var Page = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("view");
for (i = 0; i < Page.length; i++) { 
    if(Page.item(i).getAttribute("name") == 'html_header') {
         //some process
    }
    htmlString += Page.item(i).getTextContent();
}
```

Comment: It might help if you **defined `i`**! Does your JavaScript error console not give you any error messages?

Comment: sorry, i missed for loop

Answer (score 0):

Didn't test this, but try something like this:

```
Page.item(i).getTextContent();
```

Comment: but it shwoing blank <html> tags